# Can't set limits with coord_trans

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that show a geometric relationship, but have outliers. For example:

```
x = seq(0.1, 1, 0.01)
dat = data.frame(x=x, y=10^x)
dat[50:60, 2] = 10

qplot(x, y, data=dat, geom='line')
```

[image]

I'd like to plot this using a log transform and while zoomed in on part of the data. I know that I can do the first part with `coord_trans(y='log10')`, or the second part with `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2,8))`, but I haven't been able to combine them. Also, I need to keep these points around, so simply clipping them with `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2,8))` won't work for me.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to resort to the following terrible hack? Maybe an undocumented way to pass limits to `coord_trans`?

```
pow10 <- function(x) as.character(10^x)

qplot(x, log10(y), data=dat, geom='line') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=log10(seq(2,8,2)), formatter='pow10') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=log10(c(2,8)))
```

[image]

Comment: My bad. I thought I'd solved that, but I'm just not thinking straight today.

Comment: If you look at `+.ggplot` its clear that you can only apply 1 coord proto object at a time. Any more just overwrite older ones.

Comment: @James yes of course. I'm trying to set lims in coord_trans, which is hard (not possible?) even though it is easy to do them both individually...

Comment: I think you would have to write a new coord proto object that combined the features of both. You could start by looking at `str(CoordTrans)` and `str(CoordCartesian)`

Comment: Yea...maybe this is a good time to start mucking around with ggplot some more. Thanks, James.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a slightly simpler work-around:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = seq(0.1, 1, 0.01)
dat = data.frame(x=x, y=10^x)
dat[50:60, 2] = 10

plot_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
         geom_line() +
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2, 8)) +
         scale_y_log10(breaks=c(2, 4, 6, 8), labels=c("2", "4", "6", "8"))

png("plot_1.png")
print(plot_1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Yea this will work nicely. Minor ticks are at their correct location too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and struggled to solve it until looking more closely at `?coord_trans` (in v1.0.0 of ggplot2):

> **Usage**
>
> coord_trans(xtrans = "identity", ytrans = "identity", limx = NULL, limy = NULL)

So you can set the transformations and the limits at the same time, like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() +
  coord_trans(ytrans="log10", limy=c(2,8))
```

Comment: Would using the limits inside the coord_trans layer affect summaries? Or do they apply like a coord_cartesian layer (i.e. purely limiting the range displayed)?

Comment: Yes, it just limits the range displayed, it doesn't change the underlying dataset.